# Use of literal for Objective-C is deprecated error from AWS DynamoDB framework

Tags: ios, swift2

I'm having issue with AWS DynamoDB framework. XCode is giving me warning on the following line :

```
var model: AWSDynamoDBObjectModel {get set}

// This lines gives me "Use of literal for Objective-C ...
if (model.classForCoder.respondsToSelector("rangeKeyAttribute")) {
.....
}
```

I tried to fix that issue by repeleacing with this line :

```
if (model.classForCoder.respondsToSelector(Selector("rangeKeyAttribute"))) {
```

and seems that Selector is also depreciated in Swift 2.3.

Any idea how to get rid of this warning?

Comment: Have you updated to the AWS latest framework version first of all? And you have your Xcode etc. up to date?

Comment: Amazon hasn't released update for Swift 3 yet.

Comment: ok ? So...... Have you updated to the AWS latest framework version first of all? And you have your Xcode etc. up to date? Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41402926/lots-of-errors-when-trying-to-use-aws-dynamodb-with-swift-3 and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41868921/cannot-call-value-of-non-function-type-selector-bool-converting-to-swi

Comment: As I've said eariler, the latest version AWS released is for Swift 2.3. So yes, I'm using the latest Amazon has to offer. And yes, I have latest version of Xcode too.

Comment: I asked you for the version of your SDK and XCode, not what Amazon has relased or not. And the links I posted with a duplicate has already given a solution for you. Even @Matt has posted you the solution below.

Comment: I think there was miscommunication then. You kept asking me about if i have upto date versions of what Xcode and AWS has to offers and I said yes. If you specifically looking for version numbers, here you go : XCode 8.2.1, SDK IOS 10.2, AWS Mobile SDK 2.5.0. I didn't see the link you posted. I'll check it out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `#selector` syntax. It's the modern way.

Comment: I'm not sure what's proper way to use #selector but seems that it does not return value that respondsToSelector needs. It gives me "Cannot call value of non-function type (Selector)->Bool".

Comment: "I'm not sure what's proper way to use `#selector`" But the link I gave you _tells_ you the proper way.

Comment: I meant how to use #selector for that AWS method. That link you posted has good explination and helps me understand selector. However, I can't get it work AWS method I'm using and giving me an error that I mentioned. Here's how I use it : if (model.classForCoder.respondsToSelector(aSelector: #selector (AWSDynamoDBModeling.rangeKeyAttribute)))